# Given an evenly spaced array of integers, find between which 2 values an integer falls

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm having a bit of trouble writing some logic with javascript
Given an array (arr1) and test value (test)

```
arr1 = [5, 12, 19, 27]
test =15
```

Return a value of 3 for test=15, where test<5 = 1, 5< test >12=2, etc. Test can be any integer between 1 and 31 inclusive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do a simple for cycle, an if the number is lesser than the number on the i-th cell you will retyrn i.

If you start by i=0, you can do only 3 if-else statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var arr1 = [5, 12, 19, 27];
var test = 15;
var i;
for(i = 0; i < arr1.length && test > arr1[i]; i++);
console.log(i+1);
```

Logs `3`.

Your title says "Evenly spaced", but your array has a slight mistake if that's supposed to be the case (`27` should be `26`).

However, if the array *is* evenly spaced, you can do this without a loop:

```
// Assuming the array = [5, 12, 19, 26];
var test = 15;
console.log(Math.ceil((test - 5)/7)+1);
```

So, basically:

```
Math.ceil((test - startingNumber) / spacing)+1
```

Comment: Thanks, javascript is new to me.